# Excluding a label value from a specific host only

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I've below metrics in Prometheus

```
{hostname="HOST-A",mountpoint="/DIR/1"} 0
{hostname="HOST-B",mountpoint="/DIR/2"} 0
{hostname="HOST-B",mountpoint="/DIR/7"} 0
{hostname="HOST-C",mountpoint="/DIR/3"} 0
{hostname="HOST-D",mountpoint="/DIR/4"} 0
```

How can I exclude a specific mount point from a single host only?

I use below expresson to get FS utilization
`100 - (100 * node_filesystem_avail_bytes  / node_filesystem_size_bytes)`

Trying to achieve is exclude a specific host and all content inside a mount point. From `hostname="HOST-B" and mountpoint="/DIR/.*"`

current expr: `100 - (100 * node_filesystem_avail_bytes{hostname="HOST-B",mountpoint!~"/DIR/.*"}  / node_filesystem_size_bytes{hostname="HOST-B",mountpoint!~"/DIR/.*"})`

How can we modify the expression and incldue other host to the metrics returned from Prometheus

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to excldue a specific `mountpoint` value from a specific `hostname`,you can use `unless` operator of promQL to achieve this.

Query to filter out :

```
node_filesystem_avail_bytes unless node_filesystem_avail_bytes{hostname="HOST-B", mountpoint="/DIR/1"}
```

The above query will show available bytes of all hosts & mountpoints except `host-B` with mountpoint `DIR/1`